# Trying to combine two fields in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two SqlDataSources that relate to two dropdownlists. The PopulateDLL() method allows me to populate the first dropdownlist with towns and filters the second dropdownlist with street names related to that town, however some street names also have building names (i.e. City Hall, Main Street), what I'm trying to do is include the building name with the appropriate street names. I researched this and got the code

> ```
>         dt.Columns.Add("StreetName + BuildingName");
>         ddl_FilteredLocation.DataTextField = "BuildingName";
>         //ddl_FilteredLocation.DataValueField = "";
>         ddl_FilteredLocation.DataBind();
> ```

However it still only calls the street name, I've tried different variations and sometimes only the building name will appear but no street name, any help with this would be great, thanks!

```
<%-- DS for DDL Location --%>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_Location" EnableCaching="false" DataSourceMode="DataSet" runat="server" >

    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataTown %>"

    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Town FROM [DataTown].[dbo].[DT] Order By Town">
  <asp:SqlDataSource>

<%-- DS for DDL Street Name, filterExpression is used so that when a user selects a town from ddl_Location the streets for that town are filtered --%>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_StreetName" EnableCaching="true" DataSourceMode="DataSet" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataTown %>"

        SelectCommand="SELECT Town, BuildingName, StreetName FROM [DataTown].[dbo].[DT] Order By StreetName" FilterExpression="Town = '{0}'">


        <FilterParameters>
           <asp:ControlParameter Name="Town" ControlID="fmv_AccidentHSUData$ddl_Location" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>



   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Location" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_FilteredLocation" DataSourceID="ds_StreetName" DataTextField="StreetName" DataValueField="StreetName" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" runat="server">


protected void PopulateDDL()
    {
        DropDownList ddl_Location = (DropDownList)fmv_DataTown.FindControl("ddl_Location");
        DropDownList ddl_FilteredLocation = (DropDownList)fmv_DataTown.FindControl("ddl_FilteredLocation");
        ddl_Location.Items.Clear();
        DataView view = (DataView)ds_Location.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataTable dt = view.ToTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("StreetName + BuildingName");
        ddl_FilteredLocation.DataTextField = "BuildingName";
        //ddl_FilteredLocation.DataValueField = "";
        ddl_FilteredLocation.DataBind();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {

            string Town = row["Town"].ToString();
            //string StreetName = row["StreetName"].ToString();
            string FullText = "";
            if (Town.Length > 0)
            {
                FullText = Town;
            }
            else
            {

            }
            ddl_Location.Items.Add(new ListItem(FullText, FullText));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code underneath is the solution to the problem I had

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateDDL();
    }
}

protected void PopulateDDL()
    {
        DropDownList ddl_Location = (DropDownList)fmv_DataTown.FindControl("ddl_Location");
        DropDownList ddl_FilteredLocation = (DropDownList)fmv_DataTown.FindControl("ddl_FilteredLocation");
        ddl_Location.Items.Clear();
        DataView view = (DataView)ds_Location.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataTable dt = view.ToTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {

            string Town = row["Town"].ToString();
            string FullText = "";
            if (Town.Length > 0)
            {
                FullText = Town;
            }
            else
            {

            }
            ddl_Location.Items.Add(new ListItem(FullText, FullText));
        }
    }
```